# PageNumberPagination and a queryset without fixed order

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination, drf-queryset

According to the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination), nothing special is required to enable pagination when using a class inheriting from `GenericAPIView`.

I've looked in the code of django and django rest framework and the *ViewSet* queryset doesn't seem ordered. The pagination only adds the *SQL* keywords `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to the query.

What I don't understand is how is handled a queryset that doesn't have a deterministic order ? Why the documentation doesn't say to add a `.order_by()` statement at the end of the *ViewSet* queryset ?

Comment: Probably just a flaw in the documentation, although many databases have a consistent order across queries - unfortunately it is not the case with postgres, the ordering tends to change when you update the table.

Comment: In that case, this is a big flaw as it is never mentioned that the viewset queryset must be ordered when using the `PageNumberPagination`. Moreover, when using the `CursorPagination` an order is forced on the queryset by DRF.

Comment: See https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L467

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordering is required to have pagination working properly. Without that you can have few rows repeated across different pages and few missing. It is also mentioned in django docs:

> For consistent pagination, QuerySets should be ordered, e.g. with an
> order_by() clause or with a default ordering on the model.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/#required-arguments

It is also worth to read this article about default ordering: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/archive/blogs/conor_cunningham_msft/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by

Answer (score 0):

Queries without explicit order should be database specific and there is no guarantee you will get a sorted result set (unless django sorts by id as default), please see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6053) for similar answer.

Comment: I agree with you, this is why I'm surprised that it is not necessary to force an `order_by` on the queryset when using this type of pagination.